# If random variable $(X \, | \, Y=y) \sim \mathcal{B}(y,p)$ then $\mathbb{E}[X\color{red}{^n} \, | \, Y=y] = yp$?

Tags: probability

[image]

[image]

Refering to equation marked (2): I am aware if $(X \, | \, Y=y) \sim \mathcal{B}(y,p)$ then $\mathbb{E}[X \, | \, Y=y] = yp$? but if its $X^n$ where $n$ is a constant? Does it still hold? It appears so from the image (from lecture notes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a very incomplete answer.

The higher moments of the binomial are quite complicated. In particular, it is readily seen that except in the case $y=1$, they are not equal to $yp$.

You can find [some of the higher moments here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialDistribution.html) and elsewhere. For example, if a random variable $W$ has binomial distribution with parameters $(y,p)$ then $E(W^2)=yp(1-p)+y^2p^2$.

In principle, one can compute any of the moments by differentiating the moment generating function enough times. But although the moment generating function is quite simple, its derivatives soon get complicated.

Comment: So short answer is "no"? Then perhaps I misunderstood the notes? (I've uploaded to full question/answer into OP), how did they equate $\mathbb{E}[X^2 | Y=y] = yp$? (marked (2) in the images)

Comment: The notes calculate $E(X^2|Y=y)$. Third line from the end of the part you quote, it gives the same thing that I did, in slightly different but equivalent form, $p^2y(y-1)+yp$. In displayed formula (2) the author **does not** say that $E(X^2|Y=y)=yp$. She/he is in the middle of a calculation of that, and has reduced the problem to evaluating (1). **One** component of that involves evaluating (2). The second component of evaluating the sum (1) involves the part with the second derivative. After formula (2), that's what she/he is doing for a while. (Cont)

Comment: (Cont) The whole thing ends when things are put together,  third line from the end. In the last line, she/he obtains the conditional variance from that.